# Joining tables then passing to view (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, inner-join

I am looking for an appropriate way to perform an inner join of two tables in a controller, then pass the result to a view.

So far I have successfully achieved this by creating a SQL View that pulls all the required fields from the two tables, and created a model based on this SQL View. The DBContext then allows this view to be pulled into a list and passed to my index.chtml View.

Whilst this works, I am sure that there must be a way to join these two tables in the controller (without the need for a SQL View), run the query, fetch the data and pass the results to the index.chtml View somehow.

I am interested in the preferred way of achieving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you researched about [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)?

Comment: The last time I looked at SQL, a View was just a Select statemant with a name.

Comment: LINQ it the solution to your problem. You should however be aware of how LINQ works. It may not be obvious at first. LINQ first creates the query objects in memory. At some point the query has to be resolved (f.i. at the moment you use the ToList()). At that moment the SQL query to retrieve the data is created and sent to the DB. Resolving the query too early may result in slow performance and lots of traffic. Read up on LINQ before you start using it. Once you get the hang it's great fun.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.